# Porque tive que adicionar global research neste replace?

Tags: javascript, html, string

Estou tentando retirar essa cadeia de caracteres de minha string `&#8203;`.

```js
var mypage = '<div pr-compile-html="d.article.body" id="article-body" pr-highlight="" pr-highlight-tooltip="#highlight-tooltip" highlight-class="highlight" class="ng-isolate-scope"><p class="ng-scope">Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Si u mundo tá muito paradis? Toma um mé que o mundo vai girarzis! Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Si num tem leite então bota uma pinga aí cumpadi!</p><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><h1 class="ng-scope" id="h1aqui">H1aqui</h1><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><p class="ng-scope">Suco de cevadiss deixa as pessoas mais interessantis. Delegadis gente finis, bibendum egestas augue arcu ut est. Detraxit consequat et quo num tendi nada. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose.</p><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><p class="ng-scope"><span><img src="http://192.168.25.112:4444/media/images/_378df1f4c171831e82f815e0508fe6be6791fc37.jpeg" data-uid="_258868d5c512" data-md-img="http://192.168.25.112:4444/media/images/_378df1f4c171831e82f815e0508fe6be6791fc37.jpeg" data-hd-img="http://192.168.25.112:4444/media/images/_2478f370b6dac0e53c9ec2877f85b831b3271fc2.jpeg" width="713" height="401"><span class="image-caption" data-uid="_258868d5c512" style="width: 713px;">Alou sol</span></span>&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;</p><p class="ng-scope">Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum. Atirei o pau no gatis, per gatis num morreus. Aenean aliquam molestie leo, vitae iaculis nisl.</p><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><h1 class="ng-scope" id="h1aqui">H1aqui</h1><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><h2 class="ng-scope">H2aqui</h2><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><p class="ng-scope">Nullam volutpat risus nec leo commodo, ut interdum diam laoreet. Sed non consequat odio. Viva Forevis aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! In elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.</p></div>'


console.log(mypage.replace('&#8203;',''))
```

Neste trecho o replace não funcionou apesar nessa string funcionar:

```js
var x = 'AmendoBObo&#8203;';
console.log(x.replace('&#8203;',''))
```

Então descobri que se eu fizer desse jeito funcionará:

```js
var mypage = '<div pr-compile-html="d.article.body" id="article-body" pr-highlight="" pr-highlight-tooltip="#highlight-tooltip" highlight-class="highlight" class="ng-isolate-scope"><p class="ng-scope">Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Si u mundo tá muito paradis? Toma um mé que o mundo vai girarzis! Cevadis im ampola pa arma uma pindureta. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis. Si num tem leite então bota uma pinga aí cumpadi!</p><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><h1 class="ng-scope" id="h1aqui">H1aqui</h1><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><p class="ng-scope">Suco de cevadiss deixa as pessoas mais interessantis. Delegadis gente finis, bibendum egestas augue arcu ut est. Detraxit consequat et quo num tendi nada. Em pé sem cair, deitado sem dormir, sentado sem cochilar e fazendo pose.</p><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><p class="ng-scope"><span><img src="http://192.168.25.112:4444/media/images/_378df1f4c171831e82f815e0508fe6be6791fc37.jpeg" data-uid="_258868d5c512" data-md-img="http://192.168.25.112:4444/media/images/_378df1f4c171831e82f815e0508fe6be6791fc37.jpeg" data-hd-img="http://192.168.25.112:4444/media/images/_2478f370b6dac0e53c9ec2877f85b831b3271fc2.jpeg" width="713" height="401"><span class="image-caption" data-uid="_258868d5c512" style="width: 713px;">Alou sol</span></span>&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;</p><p class="ng-scope">Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Vehicula non. Ut sed ex eros. Vivamus sit amet nibh non tellus tristique interdum. Atirei o pau no gatis, per gatis num morreus. Aenean aliquam molestie leo, vitae iaculis nisl.</p><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><h1 class="ng-scope" id="h1aqui">H1aqui</h1><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><h2 class="ng-scope">H2aqui</h2><p class="ng-scope"><br></p><p class="ng-scope">Nullam volutpat risus nec leo commodo, ut interdum diam laoreet. Sed non consequat odio. Viva Forevis aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! In elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo.</p></div>'


console.log(mypage.replace(/&#8203;/g,''))
```

Porém estou sem entender o que está contencendo aqui. Porque em uma string mais simples funcionou e em meu html não funcionou?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quem disse para você que a primeira **não funcionou??** Funcionou sim, se você contar no seu código você tem **7** vezes a sequência **`&#8203;`** se você contar depois que executou sem o **g** ele fez o esperado que é cortar/excluir o primeiro conjunto de `&#8203;` encontrado, deixando as outras **6**. Para isto que serve a flag **g**, significa **global**, ou seja, ele cortará da string todas as ocorrência que derem match com a expressão regular. Link bom para conhecer mais sobre [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```js
let x = `X: &#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;`
let y = `Y: &#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;`

console.log(x.replace(/&#8203;/,'') + ' Retirou uma apenas, a primeira encontrada!');

console.log(y.replace(/&#8203;/g,'') + ' Retirou todas!');
```

Comment: Eu pensei que este replace funcionasse da mesma forma que python, subistituindo todas as ocorrências.